# Storing PointCloud2 type msgs in an octomap

Tags: octomap, ros-groovy, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am receiving a pointCloud2 type messages by subscribing to a topic, in my code. Now I need to build an octomap from this. I am currently using Groovy and Octomap libraries for ROS Groovy.

I have gone through the documentation of octomap, but couldn't retrieve much from that. The function octomap::insertPointCloud() is somewhat close to my requirement.

---

Is there a way to create an octomap using this API for the callback being received ? And can I eventually write an octomap-file to the disk using some function ?

---

I have gone through few threads like this also but not able to get a concrete idea.
http:// answers.ros.org/question/89906/how-to-generate-an-octomap-from-a-point-cloud-with-hydro/

I'd be grateful if someone can point me to an example code for the same or the order we need to follow to achieve this ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137186/storing-pointcloud2-type-msgs-in-an-octomap/) by [rosAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/9296/rosas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want a node that does the mapping for you, have a look at [octomap_server](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server). It takes point clouds with tf and builds an octomap for you that you can request e.g. with the octomap_saver node. You can also use the API in your own code.

If you want to keep it simple and just use the OctoMap API in your code then you're right, `insertPointCloud()` is the correct function. You only need to convert the point clouds into the OctoMap native type by using `conversions.h` in the package [octomap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_ros?distro=hydro).

With all this, just keep in mind that you're not actually storing the PointCloud2 in octomap, but integrate the information into the occupancy map. The actual point cloud data is discarded afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/9296/rosas/) on 2014-03-12**:
Thanks your response @AHornung, now I am using the octomap_server: I copied the "octomap_mapping.launch" file in my workspace and changed the "dataSource"
How to proceed with this kind of arrangement so that I can listen to pointcloud2  ? ("rosrun octomap_server ...") ??